# Reshape a 1D array to a masked 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, mask, reshape

OK so I have this 2D array:

```
print indgrid

[[0 6 9 3 1]
[5 9 7 4 5]
[2 8 3 8 4]
[5 6 2 6 8]
[5 3 7 7 0]]
```

I then apply a mask to it:

```
print mask

[[False False  True False False]
 [False  True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True False]
 [False False  True False False]]


print indgrid[mask]

[9 9 7 4 2 8 3 8 4 6 2 6 7]
```

So this is now a 1D array of values that have been taken out of the indgrid array. I then want to perform some calculations on these values and then when I am done, put the values calculated from each element into a 2D array which is the same shape as the `indgrid` array, so I would end up with this:

```
[[ 0 0 f 0 0 ]
[ 0 f f f 0 ]
[ f f f f f ]
[ 0 f f f 0]
[ 0 0 f 0 0 ]]
```

where `f` just represents a float that I have calculated. What is the best way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Just to say `indgrid[mask]` with the values above should give `array([0, 6, 3, 1, 5, 5, 5, 8, 5, 3, 7, 0])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgive the terrible variable names:

```
f_values = some_function_of(indgrid[mask])
result = np.zeros(indgrid.shape)
result[mask] = f_values
```

Comment: I think he wants `result[~mask] = f_values`.

Comment: Ah yes. But it looks like the question is a bit inconsistent. i.e. `indgrid[mask]` looks like it should be `indgrid[~mask]` too.

Comment: apologies, the question is inconsistent, I have fixed this now!